# MySQL Changing Order Depending On Contents of a Column

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a MySQL table Page with 2 columns: PageID and OrderByMethod.
I also then have a Data table with lots of columns including PageID (the Page the data is on), DataName, and DataDate.

I want OrderByMethod to have one of three entries: Most Recent Data First, Most Recent Data Last, and Alphabetically.

Is there a way for me to tack an "ORDER BY" clause to the end of this query that will vary its ordering method based on the contents of the "OrderByMethod" column?  For example, in this query, I would want to have the ORDER BY clause contain whatever ordering rule is stored in Page 1's OrderByMethod column.

```
GET * FROM `Data` WHERE `Data`.`PageID`=1 ORDER BY xxxxxx;
```

Maybe a SELECT clause in the ORDER BY clause?  I'm not sure how that would work though.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Data.* 
from Data
inner join Page on (Data.PageID=Page.PageID)
where Data.PageID=1
order by 
if(Page.OrderByMethod='Most Recent Data First', now()-DataDate, 
  if(Page.OrderByMethod='Most Recent Data Last', DataDate-now(), DataName)
);
```

Comment: How would I throw in a third "if" for the order-by-alphabetical option?

Comment: there is no need for third IF, cause the `DataName` is meant for alphabetically order

Comment: ah!  Very interesting!  I'll try it out now.

Comment: Very elegant and simple solution -- thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do this with the `IF` syntax to generate a column that you can then order by.

```
SELECT *, IF(Page.OrderBy = 'Alphabetically', Data.DataName, IF(Page.OrderBy = 'Most Recent Data First', NOW() - Data.DataDate, Data.DataDate - NOW())) AS OrderColumn
FROM Data
INNER JOIN Page ON Data.PageID = Page.PageID
WHERE Page.PageID = 1
ORDER BY OrderColumn
```

The direction of the ordering is determined in the calculation of the data instead of specifying a direction in the `ORDER BY`

Comment: @Carl Benson Updated with code. I'm going to try it and update the answer with more information

Comment: Perhaps some kind of if within an if?

Comment: The IF within an IF is possible but upon doing so, the data in the column would have to be re-organised such that when OrderBy is ordered, the field is sorted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just append the order by clause to the select statement and rebind the table on postback?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the content of the column in `Page` table as an expression in `ORDER BY` you have to do it using prepared statements. Let say, you store in `OrderByMethod` something like "field1 DESC, field2 ASC" and you want this string to be used as it is:

```
SET @order_by =(SELECT OrderByMethod FROM Page WHERE id = [value]);
SET @qr = CONCAT(your original query,' ORDER BY ', @order_by);
PREPARE stmt FROM @qr;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

If you want the result set to be sorted based on the value of `OrderByMethod` , you can use `IF` as it was already mentioned by others, or `CASE` :

```
...
ORDER BY 
CASE  OrderByMethod
  WHEN 'val1' THEN field_name1
  WHEN 'val2' THEN field_name2
  ....etc
END
```